# Fix ANSI control characters before PowerShell output to a file

Tags: powershell, unicode, powershell-cmdlet

Is there anyway for PowerShell to output a file without ANSI control characters like color control, e.x. `[1;xxm` or `[xm]`, before outputting to a file,

```
[1;35mStarting selenium server... [0m[1;35mstarted - PID: [0m 22860

[0;36m[Signin Test] Test Suite[0m
[0;35m================================[0m

Running:  [0;32mstep 1 - launch the browser[0m
[1;35m[40mINFO[0m [1;36mRequest: POST /wd/hub/session[0m
```

The output displays correctly with color in PowerShell terminal, (I've used `chcp`, not working)

[image: click to view image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
... | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace '\[\d+(;\d+)?m' | Add-Content 'C:\path\to\output.txt'
    $_
}
```

or wrap it in a function:

```
function Tee-ObjectNoColor {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]$InputObject,

        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$FilePath
    )

    Process {
        $InputObject -replace '\[\d+(;\d+)?m' | Add-Content $FilePath
        $InputObject
    }
}

... | Tee-ObjectNoColor -FilePath 'C:\path\to\output.txt'
```

Comment: Thank you for the regex and tee function. I will look more into cmdlets. Is there a way to eliminate all weird Unicode characters, because the output file has other characters `ΓåÆ`, and I have to manually include them in regex `|[\u001B\u0393\u00E5\u00C6]`

Comment: It might be simpler to define the non-weird characters and remove everything else.

Comment: Be aware this will remove the visible characters, but the escape character that precedes the square bracket will be retained. This escape character is non-printing so it'll be invisible, but some downstream text viewers will render that character as an ambiguous square. Also the included regex here will only find ansi codes with one or two elements, and will skip codes like `[1;35;3;38m`.

Answer (score 7):

For the windows system one could use the **Replace** command available as a part of Powershell 3.0.The powershell makes use of regex expression that helps to replace the ANSI Color codes. (In case of UNIX one could use the **sed** command )

### Using Regex

Below is the standard Regex for removing ANSI color codes (can be used in Linux and windows both)

```
'\x1b\[[0-9;]*m'
```

- `\x1b` (or `\x1B`) is the *escape* special character
  (`sed` does not support alternatives `\e` and `\033`)
- `\[` is the second character of the escape sequence
- `[0-9;]*` is the color value(s) regex
- `m` is the last character of the escape sequence

### Final Command

I am here outputting the logs of docker to a log file.One could do the same for other commands

**`docker logs container | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '\x1b\[[0-9;]*m','' }| Out-File -FilePath .\docker-logs.log`**

- ForEach-Object refers to each object from the pipped stream and $_ refers to current object.

The above command will remove the special characters like `[1;35m` , `[0m[1;3` and `^[[37mABC` from the output stream.

Comment: this command is not working

Comment: @mammadalius when making these claims it's best to provide a bit more context and information than "it's not working".