# Remove Color From Tee-Object Powershell

Tags: powershell

```
Start-Process "powershell" -ArgumentList "-noexit -executionpolicy bypass -windowstyle minimized -command `"&{Invoke-Expression `'.\$exe $Arguments`' | Tee-Object `'$Logs`'}`""
```

This command works, however the .exe I am running has color text, like:

```
[0m
```

Which makes it hard to parse the resulting .log file.

Is there way to Tee-Object to a file, and remove the color output?

Also, is there a way to do so, while keeping the color on the console, as the console displays the same characters (no color).

I have been searching up and down, re-wrote it a hundred different ways, and I can't seem to find a way to remove it.

Also, if there is cleaner way to write the launch besides `invoke-expression | Tee-Object`

It seems to be the only one that works for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fix ANSI control characters before PowerShell output to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703539/fix-ansi-control-characters-before-powershell-output-to-a-file)

Comment: I don't think you can run that while the process is running. It's meant for after its finished I think. I will try it, and see what I get. However he is stating that the output color is being displayed correctly on screen- It's not for me. The ANSII color codes are being put onto screen rather than changing color.

Comment: Tee-ObjectNoColor cmdlet says its an empty string, though I am piping it after invoke-expression.

Comment: Alternatively,

If there was a way I could use `Get-Content` to display the log to screen, and the color syntax is transformed into actual color- I could probably deal with parsing the .log file, but have the .exe outputted directly to file...Then have the powershell widow simply display the log file in place of the .exe. But I haven't figured out a way to display the color from `Get-Content` either.

Comment: I figured out the `Tee-ObjectNoColor` works- It just takes a little bit for it to start. I added to it to remove escape characters as well.

The only thing I need to solve now, is how to keep color output in the exe display.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Tee-ObjectNoColor {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]$InputObject,

        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$FilePath
    )

  process{
        $InputObject = $InputObject -replace '\\[\d+(;\d+)?m'
        $InputObject | Out-File $FilePath -Append
        $InputObject | Out-Host
         }
}
```

This is how I did it. It removes all color symbols, clean on both screen and log.

Comment: As this is in essence [Ansgar Wiechers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45709053/6811411) to my above link, **HE** would have deserved a vote up (till now the only one is mine).

Comment: His answer was wrong though. It did not work. His answer still made the screen garbled with color characters.

But I will upvote you for pointing me in the right direction. And upvote his link.