# Powershell - disable colored command output

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I'm running a command (`New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -WhatIf`) in Powershell (or Powershell Core, both are options here), that produces some very colorful output like this:

[image]

The problem is that when I run this in an Azure DevOps pipeline, the logging there gets confused by the colors and produces lots of gibberish:
[image]

So my question is: As this command itself does not have such an option, is there a general way in PowerShell (Core) to disable commands from producing colored output?

Comment: There no easy way to remove ANSI color codes from powershell. You can check this topic - [Fix ANSI control characters before PowerShell output to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703539/fix-ansi-control-characters-before-powershell-output-to-a-file) as it may help you.

Comment: Even if it's not the marked answer, use the second answer from the link @Krzysztof  mentioned. That pattern matches ANSI Escape codes correctly (including the escape char itself). Direct link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58297270/13699968

Comment: Are the links above helpful?

Comment: I found it overly complicated tbh and just gave up on it for now

Comment: This issue has been recorded on DevOps side, unfortunately there is not a perfect solution currently. You can follow this issue at following link: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1569.

Comment: thanks @CeceDong-MSFT, I subscribed to that thread

Comment: See the answer in a previous question, [Fix ANSI control characters before PowerShell output to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703539/fix-ansi-control-characters-before-powershell-output-to-a-file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix ANSI control characters before PowerShell output to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703539/fix-ansi-control-characters-before-powershell-output-to-a-file)

Answer (score 15):

With PowerShell 7.2 there's probably a new solution for you:

```ps1
$PSStyle.OutputRendering = [System.Management.Automation.OutputRendering]::PlainText;
```

From [about_ANSI_Terminals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ansi_terminals?view=powershell-7.2) document:

> The following members control how or when ANSI formatting is used:
>
> - `$PSStyle.OutputRendering` is a `System.Management.Automation.OutputRendering` enum with the values:
>
>   - **ANSI**: ANSI is always passed through as-is
>   - **PlainText**: ANSI escape sequences are always stripped so that it is only plain text
>   - **Host**: This is the default behavior. The ANSI escape sequences are removed in redirected or piped output.

You can also try to query the PowerShell help system about it:

```ps1
Get-Help -Name 'about_ANSI_Terminals';
```

A full example of use with something you have regardless of modules, etc. This:

```ps1
$PSStyle.OutputRendering = [System.Management.Automation.OutputRendering]::Ansi;
$PSVersionTable | Format-List;
```

will produce a colored output, wile this:

```ps1
$PSStyle.OutputRendering = [System.Management.Automation.OutputRendering]::PlainText;
$PSVersionTable | Format-List;
```

will produce plain-text.
If you try this:

```ps1
$PSStyle.OutputRendering = [System.Management.Automation.OutputRendering]::Host;
$PSVersionTable | Format-Table | Tee-Object -FilePath '.\output.txt';
```

you should get a colored output in your terminal/console, but plain-text in the `output.txt` file.

Also I've just found, that this was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69065907/5853770) and described in much more detail.