# Is it possible to stop `powershell` wrapping output in ANSI sequences?

Tags: windows, powershell, winapi

I `CreateProcess`(win32) `powershell` and read raw bytes from it.
And I see that it produces a lot of invisible chars.
For example `\u{1b}[2J\u{1b}[m\u{1b}[`

Is there any way how to stop it?

*Exactly it's possible to strip them manually but I do hope there other way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- You mention `powershell` (`powershell.exe`), i.e. the CLI of *Windows PowerShell*.
- **Windows PowerShell (unlike *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, see below) *itself* does *not* use coloring / formatting based on VT / ANSI escape sequences**.
- The implication is that ***third-party code* is producing the VT sequences in your case**, so you must deactivate (or reconfigure) *it* to avoid such sequences in the output.

  - A prime candidate is a custom `prompt` function; such functions often involve coloring for a better command-line experience.
  - In *programmatic* use of `powershell.exe`, however, you would only see what the prompt function prints *if you feed PowerShell commands to the CLI's stdin*, accompanied by passing argument `-File -` to the CLI (to instruct it to read commands from stdin) or by default.
  - To *exclude* the prompt-function output from the output altogether, use `-Command -`, as discussed in the [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69036873/45375).
  - If you do want it, but want to use the *default* prompt string, suppress `$PROFILE` loading with the `-NoProfile` parameter, which is generally preferable in programmatic processing.

---

#### Controlling use of colored output (VT / ANSI escape sequences) in PowerShell (Core) 7.2+

**In *PowerShell (Core) 7+* (`pwsh.exe`)** - but not in *Windows PowerShell* (`powershell.exe`) - **PowerShell *itself* situationally uses VT (ANSI) escape sequence to produce formatted/colored output**, such as in the output of [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) and, in **v7.2+**, in formatted output in general, notably **column headers** in *tabular* output / **property names** in *list* output.

- In **PowerShell 7.2+** you **can *categorically* suppress these as follows**:

  - Note: ***Categorically* disabling VT (ANSI) sequences is generally *not necessary*, because PowerShell *automatically* suppresses them when output *is not sent to the host (display)***; that is, [`$PSStyle.OutputRendering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables?view=powershell-7.2#psstyle) defaults to `Host`<sup>[1]</sup>.

    - This amounts to the same behavior that many Unix utilities (sensibly) exhibit: coloring is by default only applied when printing to the *display* (terminal), not when piping to another command or redirecting to a file.
    - However, note that `$PSStyle.OutputRendering` only applies to objects that are formatted by PowerShell's [for-display formatting system](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/formatting-file-overview) and *only when* such formatted representations are *converted to string data*, either explicitly with `Out-String`, or implicitly with `>` / `Out-File` or when piping to an *external program*.<sup>[2]</sup>
  - **From *outside* PowerShell**, *before* launching it:

    - By **defining the `NO_COLOR` environment variable**, with *any* value, such as `1`.

      - This causes PowerShell to set [`$PSStyle.OutputRendering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables?view=powershell-7.2#psstyle) to `PlainText` on startup, which instructs PowerShell not to use VT / ANSI escape sequences.
      - A growing number of *external programs* also respect this env. variable - see [no-color.org](https://no-color.org/)
    - Alternatively, by setting the `TERM` environment variable to  `xtermm` / `xterm-mono` (also sets `$PSStyle.OutputRendering` to `'plaintext'`):

      - Note that value <del>`dumb`</del>, at least as of PowerShell Core 7.3.3, *doesn't* work: while it does cause `$host.UI.SupportsVirtualTerminal` to then reflect `$false`, as documented, `$PSStyle.OutputRendering` remains at its default, `Host`, and *actual formatted output* (such as from `Get-Item /`) still uses colors.
      - However, setting `TERM` may be *more* effective than `NO_COLOR` in getting *external programs* not to emit VT sequences - ultimately, there's no guarantee however.
      - That said, modifying `TERM`, especially setting it to value `dumb`, is best avoided in general, because external programs (on Unix-like platforms) may rely on the `TERM` variable for inferring (also non-color-related) capabilities of the hosting terminal application (which setting the variable to `dumb` takes away altogether and - at least hypothetically - value `xtermm` / `xterm-mono` may misrepresent the true *fundamental* terminal type).
  - **From *inside* PowerShell**:

    - Set `$PSStyle.OutputRendering = 'PlainText'`.

      - Note that this alone - unlike the environment variables discussed above - does not affect the behavior of *external programs*.
      - However, if `$PSStyle.OutputRendering = 'PlainText'` is in effect, you can suppress *rendering* of the ANSI escape sequences in the stdout output from external programs, simply by piping to `Out-Host` or even `Out-String`, or, with collect-all-output-first behavior, by enclosing an external-program call in `(...)`; notably, this does *not* remove the escape sequences from the actual *data* (PowerShell 7.2.x *used to* do that with `Out-String` and `Out-File`, but the behavior was changed in v7.3+ - see [GitHub issue #17509](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17509)).

**Note that third-party *PowerShell* code that uses VT sequences, especially if it predates PowerShell (Core) 7+, may not respect any of the standard mechanisms** described above for disabling them (though may conceivably offer a custom mechanism).

---

<sup>[1] This applies since v7.2.0-preview.9, where `Host` was made the default and the previous default, `Automatic`, was removed altogether. In *preview* versions of v7.3.0, `Ansi` was temporarily the default, but since the official v7.3.0 release the (sensible) default is again `Host`.</sup>

<sup>[2] Notably, this means that *string* data that has embedded ANSI / VT escape sequences is *not* subject to `$PSStyle.OutputRendering` in v7.3+ (a change from v7.2), because strings aren't handled by the formatting system (they print as-is).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You can [disable ANSI output rendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ansi_terminals?view=powershell-7.2#disabling-ansi-output) by [setting the environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/changing-environment-variables#example-2) `TERM` to `dumb`:

```
SetEnvironmentVariable(TEXT("TERM"), TEXT("dumb"));
// proceed with your call to CreateProcess
```

Comment: I guess it's what I am looking for.
SetEnvironmentVariable though doesn't work like your described.
```
SetEnvironmentVariable: The term 'SetEnvironmentVariable' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
```

I do it like this [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TERM", "dumb")

But not all sequences are striped ultimately (if any) :(.

Invisible chars are present before endline and after 

```
\u{1b}[9X\r\n\u{1b}[31X\r\nEXPECTED_PROMPT>
Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:\u{1b}[28X\r\n
```

Comment: +1 for the general pointers, though I don't think they apply here; even when they do apply (PowerShell (Core) 7.2+ and its preview versions), the answer is: it's complicated.

Comment: This worked for me to stop colored output in Windows PowerShell. thanks.