# Azure Devops powershell release pipeline strange chars

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have prepared a release pipeline in Azure Devops.
The pipeline has a powershell task.
This is the inline code.

```
Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Force

Install-Module -Name Bicep -Force

Import-Module Az.Accounts -Force

$PSVersionTable
```

This is the log output:

> "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile
> -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a_temp\67e051fe-1dd4-4420-b9c0-577a882c1207.ps1'"
>
> [33;1mWARNING: Both Az and AzureRM modules were detected on this
> machine. Az and AzureRM modules cannot be imported in the same session
> or used in the same script or runbook. If you are running PowerShell
> in an environment you control you can use the 'Uninstall-AzureRm'
> cmdlet to remove all AzureRm modules from your machine. If you are
> running in Azure Automation, take care that none of your runbooks
> import both Az and AzureRM modules. More information can be found
> here: https://aka.ms/azps-migration-guide[0m
>
> [32;1mAccount                                   SubscriptionName
> TenantId                             Environment[0m [32;1m-------
> ---------------- --------                             -----------[0m
> *** xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx AzureCloud [32;1mName               : [0mxxxxxx (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) -
> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -
> [32;1m[0m*** [32;1mAccount            : [0m*** [32;1mEnvironment        : [0mAzureCloud [32;1mSubscription
> : [0mxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx [32;1mTenant             :
> [0mxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx [32;1mTokenCache         : [0m
> [32;1mVersionProfile     : [0m [32;1mExtendedProperties : [0m{}

Two questions:

- what's wrong with characters?
- what does it means this "Both Az and AzureRM modules were detected on this machine" and hot to fix it?

I searched for something but i'm confused and not able to distinguish between various things I have found.

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the newer versions of pwsh using ANSI to colour code the terminal.

You can disable it as part of your pipeline task too

More here:

[Powershell - disable colored command output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65735639/powershell-disable-colored-command-output)

Comment: I will try it. Any suggestion about the other question?

Comment: It worked, thanks. I added this at start of the script:
$PSStyle.OutputRendering = [System.Management.Automation.OutputRendering]::PlainText;

Comment: The other error is not an error, just a warning that you can't use both AzureRm and Az module in the same session due to dependency conflicts.

Comment: Good, but what are the modules in conflict of dependencies? I have 4 commands

Comment: The agents have certain modules pre-installed: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2022-Readme.md#powershell-tools. The warning is that you can't load both into the same session/script.