# How to remove special characters in string in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I need a help, please :)
I have an executable that returns a version so I call it in powershell and store the returned value

```
$version=./getversion.exe
```

Sadly the returned string contains some special formatting characters.
For the version `6.0.0` I get

```
[38;5;7m6.0.0[0m
```

Is it possible to get rid of the special characters and get just the `6.0.0` string?

Comment: That looks like [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). If you just run the exe, is the output using special colors? See also [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45709053/503046).

Comment: See if this answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/71199963/15339544

Comment: `'[38;5;7m6.0.0[0m' -replace '\[[\d;:]+m'` should do (although the "real" solution is to modify $PSStyle to prevent it in the first place as described above ^ )

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Does `$PSStyle` affect output from .exe files?

Comment: `$PSStyle` looks like it could solve my problem. But unfortunately I am using powershell 5.1 that doesn't support it.
But the other suggestion should work.