# Printing ESCAPE (U+001b) stops the command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, escaping

When I am trying to list all the ASCII characters with their Unicode category, I found that printing a control character `ESCAPE` (`U+001b`) stops commands.

For example, the following command will not return until you type `Ctrl-C` (`27` is the decimal form of `0x1b`):

```
PS C:\> "{0}" -F ([Char]27)
```

### Environment

- Windows 11 22H2 Build 22621.2861
- `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` is 5.1.22621.2506
- `$PSVersionTable.CLRVersion` is 4.0.30319.42000
- Using Windows Console Host as the default terminal application

### Question

Is there any way to prevent stopping commands when printing `U+001b` in the command?

### Edit

Option B in @mklement0's answer works for my situation. Note that I have found it doesn't work in some circumstances:

- When you run the script like this, both of Windows Console Host and Windows Terminal hang.

```
PS C:\> $consoleHelper::EnableVtSupport($false)
PS C:\> '{0}' -f [char] 27
```

- When you run the script like this,

  - In the Windows Console Host, it finishes successfully (finishes without stopping).
  - In the Windows Terminal, it requires to type `Enter` to finish.

```
PS C:\> $consoleHelper::EnableVtSupport($false); '{0}' -f [char] 27
```

- When you copy & paste the script in `.ps1` file and run `powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned .\test.ps1`,

  - In the Windows Console Host, it finishes successfully.
  - In the Windows Terminal, it finishes without stopping, but the first character after `U+001b` is missing like this:

[image]

Comment: [Char]27 is an ansi escape sequence used for controlling display output to the terminal. wikipedia: [ANSI_escape_code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) learn-microsoft: [about_ansi_terminals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ansi_terminals) Not sure a good answer is here but maybe: [how-can-i-prevent-escape-sequences-being-added-to-powershell-output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71198994/how-can-i-prevent-escape-sequences-being-added-to-powershell-output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** is that **PowerShell automatically enables [VT (Virtual Terminal) support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) for itself**, which means that the ESCAPE character ([`U+001B`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1b)), i.e. the character with Unicode code point `0x1b` (decimal `27`) is seemingly invariably interpreted *as the start of a VT (ANSI) escape sequence*:

- **An ESCAPE *alone* is therefore an *incomplete* escape sequence and therefore causes the *ostensible* hang, on *Windows only*** (on *Unix*-like platforms, there is simply *no visible output*).
- What actually happens on Windows is that the incomplete escape sequence causes the next PowerShell *prompt not to render*, but subsequent command input *is* accepted and can be submitted as usual, with one exception: pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> *alone* doesn't work, but if you submit a *space* followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>, a no-op command executes and the prompt returns to normal.
  Note that this applies equally to regular console windows and sessions in Windows Terminal.

---

**Workarounds**:

Note: The following assumes that you want to print the ESCAPE character as it would if VT support were *disabled*, which is as `←`
This symbol, when interpreted as a *printable character in its own right* rather than the visualization of a *control character*, is the following Unicode character: `←` (LEFTWARDS ARROW, [`U+2190`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2190))

- **Option A**: Simply **replace the actual ESCAPE character with the LEFTWARDS ARROW for the purpose of *display output***:

  ```bash
  $c = [char] 0x1b   # same as: [char] 27
  '{0}' -f ($c -replace [char] 0x1b, [char] 0x2190)
  ```

  - While this avoids the "hang", it has the following **limitations**:

    - It changes what *data* your script outputs (though that may not matter)
    - To visualize *other* control characters as if VT support were turned off, you'd have to provide analogous replacements for them too.
- **Option B**: ***temporarily disable* VT support**:

  - This is the more comprehensive solution, but has the following **limitations**:

    - It **requires P/Invoke calls to the WinAPI**, which in turn requires ad-hoc compilation of C# code, which incurs a **once-per-session performance penalty**.
    - If you explicitly turn VT support back on as part of your script, as shown below, an attempt to *indirectly* print to the console, such as by enclosing the invocation of your script in `(...)` or piping to `Write-Host`, `Out-Host`, or `Write-Output`, the "hang" will again occur.
      The alternative is to let PowerShell *automatically* reenable it, *the next time it prints its prompt* in an interactive session.
    - **Important**: It follows from the fact that PowerShell automatically reenables VT support on returning to the interactive prompt after executing a command that **the VT-disabling call must be part of a *single command invocation***, such as part of a *script file* or script block. Thus, if you want to try the solution *interactively* - assuming `$consoleHelper` is already defined - paste either a *single-line* command  `$consoleHelper::EnableVtSupport($false); '{0}' -f [char] 27` or - in case of a multiline string, enclose it in `& { ... }` (`& { $consoleHelper::EnableVtSupport($false); '{0}' -f [char] 27 }`) - the latter ensures execution as a single command irrespective of paste method (pasting *multiline* strings can result in *multiple* command executions).

```bash
# Compile a helper type with P/Invoke declarations for enabling / disabling VT support.
# Note: This incurs a once-per-session peformance penalty.
$consoleHelper = Add-Type -PassThru -Namespace "NS$PID" -Name ConsoleHelper -MemberDefinition @'
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
  static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, int mode);
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
  static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr handle, out int mode);
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
  static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int handle);

  public static void EnableVtSupport(bool enable = true) {
    IntPtr outHandle = GetStdHandle(-11); // -11 == STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    int mode;
    GetConsoleMode(outHandle, out mode);
    SetConsoleMode(outHandle, enable ? (mode | 0x4) : (mode & ~0x4)); // 0x4 == ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING
  }
'@

# Temporarily turn off VT support.
$consoleHelper::EnableVtSupport($false)

# This now does NOT cause the "hang" and prints "←" instead.
'{0}' -f [char] 27

# == OPTIONAL PART

# Re-enable it (see caveat above).
$consoleHelper::EnableVtSupport($true)

# Verify that VT support is back on: the word "green" should print in green.
# Note: In PS 7+ you could use `e inside "..." to produce ESCAPE chars:
#   "It ain't easy being `e[32mgreen`e[m."
'It ain''t easy being {0}[32mgreen{0}[m.' -f [char] 27
```

Output, showing that the ESCAPE character was printed as `←` - implying that VT support was effectively *disabled* at the time, as desired (which avoids the "hang") - as well as the later *re-enabled* VT support resulting in the word "green" printing in green:

[image: screenshot of output]

Comment: Thank you for your information! Option B looks suitable for my situation, but `$consoleHelper::EnableVtSupport($false)` doesn't work in my environment (I have added environment information in the question). The last line of the script shows the `green` in green characters, both in Windows Console Host and Windows Terminal. Are there any prerequisites in the script?

Comment: @SATOYusuke, the last line is _supposed to_ show the word "green" in green - it is meant to demonstrate that turning VT support _back on_ works. The relevant part is the code above that: when I run the script in Windows PowerShell on Windows 11,  `'{0}' -f [char] 27` does _not_ "hang" and prints `←`. Isn't that what you wanted? Do you get different results?

Comment: @SATOYusuke, please see my update, which hopefully makes things clearer, and adds a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I have confirmed Option B works for my situation (runs `.ps1` in Windows Console Host). I have added the result of confirmation in some conditions in the question.

Comment: Thanks, @SATOYusuke. As for the update to your question: That submitting _two commands_ doesn't work is expected, given that PowerShell _automatically re-enables_ VT support in an interactive session after returning to the prompt - I've updated the answer to make that clearer. However, I can _not_ reproduce your other symptoms, and the only reason I can think of is that you're running an older Windows Terminal version; mine is v1.18.3181.0